Querying auth.users table in Supabase
I have the following function defined in the database:
BEGIN
create or replace function get_prof(email text)
returns json as $$
declare
  user_profile json;
begin
  -- Direct query to auth.users (authentication-related data)
  select row_to_json(u) into user_profile
  from auth.users u
  where u.email = email;

  -- Return the JSON result
  return user_profile;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
END;

I want to use this function for getting the first and last name of a user by its email.
However, when I try to access the function I get:
permission denied for schema public
I already executed: grant select on auth.users to authenticated
(I made sure user's role is authenticated)
How can I access the function?
